# ValueError: Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, nltk

In Spam data sheet, column (v1) has 2 values : ham & spam. When trying to
create a separate column to categorize them to 1 & 0, getting the
below error. Please assist.

```
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['output'])
if spam['v1'] == 'ham':
output == 1
else: output == 0
data = data.append(pd.DataFrame({'output': output}, index=[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
data['output'] = df['v1'].replace({'ham': 1, 'spam': 0})
```

Comment: Thanks Jeril, this is working now.